# UITableCell not resizing properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

While working on my first iPhone app, I ran into a problem while attempting to use ‘automatic’ table cell resizing. When I load the app, the first few cells will always be huge, about 6 times the size it should be. Then, when I scroll down and back up, they’ll reset to the height they should be. (See image for example, hard to explain)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWgJg.jpg (first 2 images)

So far I've tried a number of tutorials and stackoverflow answers that I couldn't post here because I can only post 2 links, most of them simply involved adding the UITableViewAutomaticDimension attribute.

I’ve made the cell in the storyboard (contains 4 labels all with # lines set to 0 and 3 images (see third image)) and gave it an identifier, then made a custom class for it to change the labels’ text.

Resizing cell like so:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 104
```

Using the following line seems to fix the issue on most devices, but it still continues to exist on the iPhone 6 plus (fourth image):

```
tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(indexesInRange: NSMakeRange(0, self.tableView.numberOfSections())), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
```

Drawing the cell:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->   UITableViewCell {
    var cell:TableCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableCell") as? TableCell

    if cell == nil {

        cell = TableCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "tableCell")
    }

    cell?.lblObituaryName.text = obituaryArray[indexPath.row].name
    cell?.lblObituaryBirth.text = obituaryArray[indexPath.row].dateOfBirth
    cell?.lblObituaryDeath.text = obituaryArray[indexPath.row].dateOfDeath
    cell?.lblObituaryPlace.text = obituaryArray[indexPath.row].city

    cell?.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    cell?.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()


    return cell!
}
```

Cell setup in storyboard is the 5th and last image.

Cell constraints:

```
Table cell is 104.0 high

Main title label:
Trailing space to: Superview = 0
Leading space to: Superview = 0
Top space to: Superview = 0
Bottom space to: Label1 = 6
Bottom space to: Label1Image = 1

Label 1:
Trailing space to: Superview = 0
Leading space to: Label1Image = 5
Bottom space to: Label2 = 6
Top space to: Main Label = 6

Label 1 Image:
Leading space to: Superview = 0
Width = 25
Height = 25
Trailing space to: Label1 = 5
Bottom space to: Label2Image = -3
Top space to: Main Label = 1

Label 2:
Trailing space to: Superview = 0
Leading space to: Label2Image = 5
Bottom space to: Label3 = 6
Top space to: Label2 = 6

Label 2 Image:
Leading space to: Superview = 0
Width = 25
Height = 25
Trailing space to: Label2 = 5
Bottom space to: Label3Image = -3
Top space to: Label1Image = -3

Label 3:
Trailing space to: Superview = 0
Bottom space to: Superview = -1
Leading space to: Label3Image = 5
Top space to: Label2 = 6

Label 3 Image:
Leading space to: Superview = 0
Width = 25
Height = 25
Trailing space to: Label3 = 5
Top space to: Label2Image = -3
```

**Fixed the error below by changing the constraint priorities to 999. Still looking for an answer for the question above though.**

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 

(

    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a0affb0 UILabel:0x7a079ea0'Mw. J.H. Zwierenga'.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7a074170.topMargin>",

    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a0b00a0 V:[UILabel:0x7a079ea0'Mw. J.H. Zwierenga']-(6)-[UILabel:0x7a0394f0'21 May 2015']>",

    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a0b0190 V:[UILabel:0x7a0394f0'21 May 2015']-(6)-[UILabel:0x7a0a1f20'1 December 1935']>",

    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a0b0280 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7a074170.bottomMargin == UILabel:0x7a094e10'Oudeschild'.bottom - 1>",

    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a0b02b0 V:[UILabel:0x7a0a1f20'1 December 1935']-(6)-[UILabel:0x7a094e10'Oudeschild']>",

    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a0b2fe0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7a074170(0)]>"

)



Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 

<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a0b02b0 V:[UILabel:0x7a0a1f20'1 December 1935']-(6)-[UILabel:0x7a094e10'Oudeschild']>



Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.

The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Let me know if any more information is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to use [layoutIfNeeded](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutIfNeeded) for update constraint immediately.
2. For fix warning, you should set one of your vertical constraint priority to 999.

**All works properly if set Accessory view to None**

Comment: Setting some vertical and horizontal constraints to 999 did indeed fix the error. Unfortunately, using layoutIfNeeded didn't change anything. Maybe I'm using it wrong? Tried calling it on the entire cell and on the label causing the issues in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: Can you create test project with you cell on github? I fix them, and write solution here.

Comment: I try many crunch =) and nothing help. But if you set accessory view cell property to None, autoLayout work properly. Fast  solution replace accessory view with custom UIImageView.

Comment: I must've done something wrong when I first started this project then. I'll just leave it at a fixed size then. Thanks for taking your time to try it with my project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
        return 104;
}
```

Comment: This does indeed stop the cells from being abnormally huge like in the screenshots I showed, but then the label doesn't split into multiple lines (http://i.imgur.com/q1Uvbos.png)

Comment: have you set  label.numberOfLines = 0;?

Comment: Via the storyboard yeah, just tried it programmically too but still breaks the tail off. When I set 'Line Breaks' to Word Wrap it doesn't show the second line either.

Comment: you can use label.sizeToFit(); for dynamic label size or increase your label height so it will create enough space for the text

Comment: Same result, the end of the name still gets cut off in the end. For some reason it won't move onto the next line. :(

Comment: make sure you are calling sizeToFIt() after following line
cell?.lblObituaryName.text = obituaryArray[indexPath.row].name

Comment: Yep, this is what I've got in the cellForRowAtIndexPath (formatting looks a bit odd): cell?.lblObituaryName.text = obituaryArray[indexPath.row].name  
        cell?.lblObituaryName.sizeToFit()

Comment: well, i think you will get better answer by search for dynamic label sizing or adaptive multiple line label